# How to call a function from a DLL file from [ MQL5 ] code?

Tags: c#, algorithmic-trading, mql4, mql5, metatrader5

**Why** the first **`MessageBox()`** works and the second doesn't?

I don't know where the problem is.

Does the **`MQL5`** can access the `dll` file?

I need to to call `C#` functions that read **`JSON`**.

No errors appear in <kbd>MetaEditor</kbd>.

**`C# .dll`** file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace TestMe
{
    class Test
    {

   // [DllExport("Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int Add(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }


    public static int Sub(int left, int right)
    {
        return left - right;
    }


    public static double AddDouble(double left, double right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }


    public static float AddFloat(float left, float right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
}
```

this is an **`MQL5`** code:

```
#import "TestMe.dll"
                    int    Add(       int    left, int    right );
                    int    Sub(       int    left, int    right );
                    float  AddFloat(  float  left, float  right );
                    double AddDouble( double left, double right );
#import

#property strict                 // MQL-syntax-mode-modifier == "strict"

int OnInit()
{   int k = 0;
    MessageBox( k );             // this call works
    k = Add( 1, 666 );
    MessageBox( k );             // Doesn't work

    return( INIT_SUCCEEDED );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Welcome** to the
**Wild
Worlds of `MQL`**

### How to test a DLL-function call access?

This is the easiest part. Test it from inside `DLL`. Add some input/output parameters/values printing on **`stdout`** into each `DLL`-function source and during the debugging-phase you have all the needed `C#`-side self-diagnostics covered there.

**`MQL`**-side also needs to have all DLL-calls permitted, check the <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 5</kbd> settings:
<sub>`[x] Allow DLL imports ...`</sub>.

---

### Syntax matters: check calling-signature(s) item by item

**`MQL`** documentation states a single, clear call-signature for **`MessageBox()`** to be used:

> `int` **`MessageBox(`**
>  
>   `string` **`text`**`,                     // message text`
>   `string` **`caption = NULL`**`,          // box header`
>   `int`**`flags       = 0`**`);           // defines set of buttons in the box`
>   **`Parameters :`**
>   **`text`**`:            [in]` Text, containing message to output.
>   **`caption`**`= NULL : [in]` Optional text to be displayed in the box header. If the parameter is empty, Expert Advisor name is shown in the box header.
>   **`flags`**`= 0 :      [in]` Optional flags defining appearance and behavior of a message box. Flags can be a combination of a special group of flags.  <sub>( *Plus: **Default** value == 0 ==* **`MB_OK`** )</sub>
>   **`Return Value :`**
> If the function is successfully performed, the returned value is one of values of `MessageBox()` return codes.  <sub>( *Which are*: `{ IDOK | IDCANCEL | IDABORT | IDRETRY | IDIGNORE | IDYES | IDNO | IDTRYAGAIN | IDCONTINUE }` )</sub>

---

### `MQL` is not C#
`MQL`-string is not a **`string`** in fact, but a **`struct`**
`MQL` is not forgiving any single tiny detail:
*due care is a must*:

**`MQL`** documentation states:

> Internal representation of the string type is a structure of 12 bytes long:

```
#pragma pack(push,1) 
struct MqlString 
  { 
   int      size;       // 32-bit integer, contains size of the buffer, allocated for the string. 
   LPWSTR   buffer;     // 32-bit address of the buffer, containing the string. 
   int      reserved;   // 32-bit integer, reserved. 
  }; 
#pragma pack(pop,1)
```

**This is `The Strange Answer` to why the first call worked.**
 The `MessageBox()` did not try to access any memory location on it's call, as the faked MQL-string-struct (ill)-declared by itself, via the `.size` struct-component it's own `.buffer` memory area ( addressed indirectly ) to have 0 bytes in length and thus **no memory area** ( ultimately colliding, by definition, with an address space of some other memory-object ) **will be, in this specific case accessed.**

After more than a decade in `MQL` domain, with more than a few hundreds man*years hands-on team experience with creeping `MQL` language-syntax, I may dare state, **"do not rely on no errors being reported in a compilation phase"**, <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal</kbd> has made us hair-less in many circumstances, even when the code was following published documentation word-by-word.

Feel free to check other posts on MQL to see more details on DLL-integration nightmares and also good stories about going into distributed processing, **`GPGPU`**-computing et al.

---

### Final remark on `JSON`

If I were to design an architecture to communicate via `JSON` I would jump in with **`ZeroMQ DLL`** distributed-processing services, that would make your goal much faster, than building just another JSON-parser as a greenfield project.