# How to read a JSON from a URL in MQL5?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mql5

How can I read **`JSON`** from a url in **`MQL5`**?

For example this simple `JSON` from: https://api.myjson.com/bins/56z28

```
{ "employees": [ { "firstName": "John",
                   "lastName":  "Doe"
                   },
                 { "firstName": "Anna",
                   "lastName":  "Smith"
                   },
                 { "firstName": "Peter",
                   "lastName":  "Jones"
                   }
                 ]
  }
```

Comment: Because of the limitations listed below, any production grade `MQL4/MQL5` system shall work with an external, distributed `JSON` communicator/processor, as noted in a trailer section in an answer to your previous question >>> stackoverflow.com/a/36863108/3666197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, but restrictions apply.

MetaTrader Terminal 5 is a code-execution environment, that can communicate with an external URL target (if explicitly configured as a permitted URL) via both HTTP/HTTPS protocols over port 80/443 respectively.

```
   string aCookieHOLDER = NULL,
          aHttpHEADERs;

   char   postBYTEs[],
          replBYTEs[];    
   int    aRetCODE;
   string aTargetURL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/56z28";

                    /*  to enable access to the URL-> pointed server,
                        you should append "https://api.myjson.com/bins/56z28"
                        to the list of allowed URLs in
                        ( Main Menu -> Tools -> Options, tab "Expert Advisors" ):
                        */
   ResetLastError();                     // Reset the last error code
   int    aTIMEOUT = 5000;               // less than 1 sec. is NOT
                                         // enough for slow Internet connection
   aRetCODE = WebRequest( "GET",
                          aTargetURL,
                          aCookieHOLDER,
                          NULL,
                          aTIMEOUT,
                          postBYTEs,
                          0,
                          replBYTEs,
                          aHttpHEADERs
                          );
   if ( aRetCODE == EMPTY )             // Check errors
   {    Print( "Error in WebRequest(). Error code  = ", GetLastError() );    
     }
   else
   {    // Load was successful, PROCESS THE STRING ... assumed to be a JSON
   }
```

As noted in code, to use the `WebRequest()` function, one has to add the addresses of all the required `URL`s (servers) a-priori in the list of allowed `URL`s in the "Expert Advisors" tab of the "Options" window. Server port is automatically selected on the basis of the specified protocol - `80` for "`http://`" and 443 for "`https://`" (not a free option...).

The `WebRequest()` function *is synchronous*, which means its breaks/blocks(!) the program execution and waits for the response from the requested URL. Since the delays in receiving a response can be large, the function is not available for calls from the indicators, because indicators run in a common thread shared by all indicators and charts on one symbol. Indicator performance delay on one of the charts of a symbol may stop updating of all charts of the same symbol (!!!!).

The function can be called only from `Expert Advisors` and `scripts`, as they run in their own execution threads. If you try to call the function from a `Custom Indicator`, `GetLastError()` will return error `4060` – `"Function is not allowed for call".`

`WebRequest()` *cannot* be executed in the Strategy Tester.

---

Bad news?

If all this sounds as a bad news to your Project, do not give up. MQL code can call DLL-functions, so one can integrate a fair, distributed, non-blocking communicator, that cooperates with MQL code smoothly and does not include any of the above listed limitations in a production system.

Comment: Your previous question already tried DLL calls >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/36863108/3666197 and JSON was mentioned there too.

Comment: Can you show me small example how can I call function from dll file?

Comment: Not exactly, the mentioned URL is extended by a group of parameters, that are not part of the URL, but are intended to be handed over to a remote **HttpServer**-side process, that may ( but need not ) include 'em into response-processing ( using them or not, inside the remote content-cooking recipe ).