# How to fix serialization problems MQL4?

Tags: c++, dll, mql4, metatrader4, metatrader5

Today I get problems with serialization in **`MQL4`**.

I have a method, which I imported from a **`DLL`**:

In **`MQL4:`**

```
void insertQuery( int     id,
                  string  tableName,
                  double &values[4],
                  long   &times[3],
                  int     volume
                  );
```

In **`DLL:`**

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall insertQuery( int      id,
                                                  wchar_t *tableName,
                                                  double  *values,
                                                  long    *times,
                                                  int      volume
                                                  );
```

I tested it with this function calls in **`MQL4:`**

```
string a      = "bla";
double arr[4] = { 1.1, 1.3, 0.2, 0.9 };
long     A[3] = { 19991208, 19991308, 19992208 };
int volume    = 1;
insertQuery( idDB, a, arr, A, volume );
```

Inside of this method I collect this values to files.

**`C++`** :

```
stringstream stream;
stream << " '";
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    stream << times[i] << "' , '";
}
stream << times[2] << ", ";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    stream << values[i] << ", ";
}

stream << volume;
wstring table(tableName);
query.append("INSERT INTO ");
query.append(table.begin(), table.end());
query.append(" VALUES (");
query.append(stream.str());
query.append(" )");

std::ofstream out("C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\text.txt");
out << query;
out.close();
```

But in output file I receive this record:

```
INSERT INTO bla VALUES ( '19991208' , '0' , '19991308, 1.1, 1.3, 0.2, 0.9, 1 )
```

**So my question is :** why I lose one **`long`** value in array when I receive my record in `DLL`?

I tried a lot of ways to solve this problem ( I transfered two and three `long` values, etc ) and **always** I get a result that I lose **second** `long` value at serialization. **Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is cause because in MQL4, a `long` is an 8 bytes, while a `long` in C++ is a 4 bytes.

1. What you want is a `long long` in your C++ constructor.
2. Or you could also pass them as strings, then convert them into the appropriate type within your C++ code.

Comment: Yes, Joseph, +1 for pointing out a triple `c-long` mis-aligned reading **just the first three halves** of the `MQL4-long times[3]` memory, thus making the zero from the upper 32bits from the first `19991208`.

Comment: Thank you, Joseph, you are really help me :)

Answer (score 1):

### Well, be carefull, ***New-*`MQL4.56789`** is not a c-compatible language

The first thing to test is to avoid passing **`MQL4 string`** into `DLL` calling interface, where really a `c-lang string` is expected.

Since old-`MQL4` has been silently re-defined into a still-WIP-creeping syntax *New-*`MQL4`,
the **`MQL4`** *string* **is not** a `string`, but a **`struct`**.

---

### Root-cause [ *isolation* ]:

Having swallowed the shock about `string/struct` trouble, if you can, **first** try to test the `MQL4/DLL` interactions without passing any `string` to proof, that all other parameters, passed by value and addressed by-ref, do get their way to the hands of a `DLL`-function as you expect.

If this works as you wish, proceed to the next step:

### How to pass the very data to expected `string` representation, then?

Let me share a dirty hack I used for passing data where `DLL` expects `string`-s

```
#import     "mql4TOOL.dll"
               ...
               int      mql4TOOL_msg_init_data ( int   &msg[],
                                                 uchar &data[],
                                                 int    size
                                                 );
               ...
#import
...
int                tool_msg_init_data ( int &msg[], string data, int size ) {  uchar dataChar[]; StringToCharArray( data, dataChar );
      return ( mql4TOOL_msg_init_data (      msg,          dataChar, size ) );
   }
```

Yes, dirty, but works for years and saved us many tens-of-man*years of re-engineering upon a maintained code-base with heavy dependence on the `MQL4/DLL` interfacing in massively distributed heterogeneous computing systems.

### The last resort:

If all efforts went in vain, go low level, passing a **`uchar[]`** as needed, where you assemble some serialised representation in `MQL4` and parse that on the opposite end, before processing the intended functionality.

### **Ugly?**

Yes, might look like that,
but
**keeps you focused on core-functionality** and **isolates you from any *next* shift of paradigm** if not only `strings` cease to be `strings` et al.

Comment: **You might also like** another post on `MQL4` / **`SER/DES` issues**  >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/36985087/3666197